# ARIMA checking and validation in R

Tags: r

I want to validate and check the ARIMA model from my data wihch results to be (0,1,1)x(0,1,1)_12.
[image]

I want to determine the parameters of such model with R and after make a cross prediction. 
I have applied:

```
parameters  <- arima(x1_1_12, c(0, 1, 1),
               seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12)))
Coefficients:
      ma1     sma1
  -0.4018  -0.5569
s.e.   0.0896   0.0731

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0002543:  log likelihood = 353.96,  aic = -701.92
```

I want to obtain the p-values and estimate the model parameters and finally check the model.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have already estimated model parameters - they're right there in your output!

As for p-values, see this post:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/how-to-calculate-the-p-value-of-parameters-for-arima-model-in-r

As for 'check the model' -- that kind of depends on what, exactly, you mean by that.